# How to put multiple rows of data from table into JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to select the last 4 rows of my table and then put them into a JSON array with a number attached to each piece of data so I can access them later, I would think a loop but don't know how to do it with the counter being the number

The part that gets the last four rows

```
SELECT title FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
```

And the array be like `1: data one, 2: data two...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aron you can use the following code:-

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "sakila");
$x = 1;
$return_arr = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT title from questions ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 4");
while( $obj = $result->fetch_object() ) {
   $row_array[$x] = $obj->title;
   $x++;
}
$result->close();
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
echo json_encode($return_arr);`//result [{"1":"title1","2":"title2","3":"title3}]
```

Here in the loop, I am storing the value inside an array($row_array). Here $x will contain the number(key). Then the complete result is pushed into a new array and the result is converted into a json array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a database connection string, such as using MySQLI.
2. Query the database for your rows.
3. Use the fetchAll() function to grab all rows, pass MYSQLI_NUM constant to tell it to return a numericaly indexed array as opposed to associative
4. json_encode and echo it back.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT title FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4');
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(MYSQLI_NUM));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code using PDO, you can change to mysqli also

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:33060;dbname=demo', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

//Key should be string, otherwise, we can not encode as json
foreach($result as $key => $value) { 
    $newkey = sprintf('%s',$key);
    $newArray["k$newkey"] = $value; 
} 

echo json_encode($newArray); //result: {"k0":"title 4","k1":"title 3","k2":"title 2","k3":"title 1"}
```